# Работа с telegram. Многоуровневый хендлер

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Не понимаю как реализовать общение с ботом. Мне необходимо написать боту сообщение, которое будет запускать специальную функцию, внутри которой пользователь будет отвечать произвольные ответы на несколько вопросов, а бот будет с ними работать.
Пытался делать дерево из `@bot.message_handler()`, но они не успевают сработать, так как стандартный `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])` с главным меню ловит сообщение быстрее

Comment: используйте FSM

Answer (score 0):

Python выполняется сверху вниз. Вы можете @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) вынести в самый низ кода и тогда он будет обрабатываться последним. Так же рекомендую start вынести в верх кода.